# Creating multiple sites with django

Tags: python, django

I have to create a project in django where the admin can create the sites dynamically and assign the administrators for the same, which would manage that particular site.

Can someone please suggest with some hint on how it can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with [django sites](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/), extend the User profile and write a custom auth in a similar way as in this question: [1404131/how-to-get-unique-users-across-multiple-django-sites-powered-by-the-sites-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404131/how-to-get-unique-users-across-multiple-django-sites-powered-by-the-sites-frame)