# django application with multiple sites - how to restrict access for staff

Tags: python, django

I made a django application recently with multiple settings files, each setting file has its own SITE_ID and each SITE_ID is associated with site_id from the django_site table. Now, I want to create staff for certain sites only and other admins for all sites, how would I do something like that?

best wishes,

Answer (score 1):

Mo - not sure whether you're still looking for an answer for this but [this cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1404131/378136) could be along the lines of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I have bad news for you, you'll have to implement it on your own. What can
you do is to implement a new class say SiteUsers, it can look as follows:

```
class SiteUsers(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

then you can use a kind of user_passes_test decorator to force access control. I'm not aware
of any ready to use solution.

another option would be to use groups. create set of groups for each site and sort users
to those groups. I think you'll have to have groups like:
     site_1_add, site_1_delete, site_1_....
     site_2_add, site_2_delete, site_2_....

however I'm afraid it does not scale so well. you will not find out unless you'll try.

anyway going either way will require a lot of admin customization. I really would need to do some research myself first.

Comment: I could apply this model, but am not entirely sure how would I restrict the access from the admin page? if you can give me more clue, i would appreciate it