# Unique username with django sites framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-sites

I have created multiple sites, that has user identification like here:

[How to get unique users across multiple Django sites powered by the "sites" framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404131/how-to-get-unique-users-across-multiple-django-sites-powered-by-the-sites-fram)

But, how to make user unique for every website where he registered ?

For example:

```
Arti at domain.com

Arti at domain2.com
```

It's two different users, but create another `Arti at domain.com` impossible, and i'll get an error: "User is already exist".

Comment: Same thing, just use an extended User model that has a foreign key to `sites` and make both `site_id` and `username` "unique_together".