# Django: User only access to certain subdomain

Tags: python, django, authentication, permissions

I got subdomains setup via [django-subdomains](https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains) and the django sites framework but I got problem and that is that I don't know how I can link Users to have access to only a certain subdomain. For example user1 from company1 only has acces to company1.arandomdomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here [How to get unique users across multiple Django sites powered by the "sites" framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404131/how-to-get-unique-users-across-multiple-django-sites-powered-by-the-sites-fram)

In short you have to write your own authentication backend to check for they condition you need to check. See docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

In my case I had to check first if the user is an admin so he/she can go and otherwise I had to check the userprofile which is linked a site and match that to the current site.